# How can I restore a microsoft sql server database backup to postgres?

Tags: sql-server, backup, postgresql, restore, dump

I need to take a Microsoft SQL Server database backup (dump) file and import/restore into a PostgreSQL database.  Does anybody have some sort of transform script (maybe a perl/sed/awk script) that could be run on the MSSQL Server backup file, so that it could be restored to the PostgreSQL database?  Let's assume the tables have already been created in postgres, but they are all empty.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with this article from the [Postgresql site](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding)

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could export data from MSSQL in CSV format (using MSSQL Enterprise Manager) and then import the CSV files into Postgresql ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgres-table) there is an example).
I suggest to export one CSV per table, so you can better manage any constraint rule.